# Can sleeping dockerized mysql processes cause high system load?

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, load-average

I'm in the process of finding out what could cause a huge system load at night. Icinga2 reports a CRITICAL state at 2:15 am:

```
load average: 49.23, 24.50, 10.24.
```

I've checked the syslog and found nothing conspicuous. I checked if the backups (rsnapshot from a different server) might cause this, but they are already finished when the system load goes up. I also checked all cronjobs, but there's nothing that could cause that load.

I've read in other answers here that zombie processes could be causing this behavior, but I can't find any (albeit at daytime). Instead, I noticed that I seem to have a lot of `Ss+` processes from my dockerized databases:

```
root        4152  0.0  0.0 713360 10572 ?        Sl    2022 105:51 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id 13b…d06
systemd+    4205  1.4  1.4 7182124 1976072 ?     Ssl   2022 8895:53  \_ mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
root     3886095  0.0  0.0  17416  7248 pts/0    Ss+  Jan30   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     3886482  0.0  0.0  17416  9704 ?        Ss+  Jan30   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     3886773  0.0  0.0  17416 11040 ?        Ss+  Jan30   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     3886934  0.0  0.0  17416 10792 ?        Ss+  Jan30   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     1100756  0.0  0.0  17532 11320 ?        Ss+  Feb17   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     2322075  0.0  0.0   4240  2356 ?        Ss   Apr11   0:00  \_ bash
root     2322108  0.0  0.0  14904  8764 ?        S+   Apr11   0:00  |   \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     1982142  0.0  0.0   4240  2496 ?        Ss   Jun01   0:00  \_ bash
root     1982345  0.0  0.0  17564 11480 ?        S+   Jun01   0:00  |   \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root      482523  0.0  0.0  17484 11344 ?        Ss+  Jun15   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     1836142  0.0  0.0  17588 11256 ?        Ss+  Aug02   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     2749207  0.0  0.0  17900 11612 ?        Ss+  Sep12   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root     2820762  0.0  0.0  17900 11452 ?        Ss+  Sep12   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root       29733  0.0  0.0  17892 11572 ?        Ss+  Sep13   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
root      272599  0.0  0.0  17644 11288 ?        Ss+  Sep13   0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxx
```

This is what I see at daytime. Is this a normal behavior and could it be the reason for the hight load average?

System information:

- 12 x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
- MemTotal: 131835028 kB
- MemFree:    4614852 kB
- MemAvailable:   89576416 kB

I'm currently running 19 docker containers (some productive, some development) on that machine. Please let me know if I should provide you with more information. Thanks!

Comment: Let's take a look at 'Sleep' ing processes with this query. -  
    SELECT 'SLEEPING Ram use', 
COUNT(*),SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) 
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE 
command="Sleep";   at 1 AM.   What are the processes hanging around since Jan, Feb, Apr, Jun and Sep?  Sounds like someone is not closing the Terminal, Getty type sessions when done.

Comment: What size are the docker containers?  How much data in the databases?

Comment: @digijay       Please post some of the information requested so someone can provide assistance.

Comment: Hi Wilson, first of all thanks for your help! I'm sorry, I don't find the time for this at the moment. I'll come back to this as soon as possible.

Comment: Looking forward to assisting you when the time is right for you.